# How to run a predicate on ObjectInstance property of DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatrigger, objectdataprovider

I have a list saved in the ObjectInstance of the ObjectDataProvider class. When calling my datatrigger i would like to run a predicate on the list and return a value true/false so i can hide/show text.
Ideally i would like to call a property "Noresults" that would return true/false so i can toggle text in the view.

```xml
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ObjectDataProvider.NoResults, Mode=OneWay,Source={StaticResource DongleContentsProvider}, BindsDirectlyToSource=True}" Value="true">
    <Setter TargetName="NoResults" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [`Binding.Converter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) which does run any logic and returns a respective bool.